# href anchor text after </a>

Tags: html, anchor, href

The following code was found on a website. Is it valid HTML?

```
<td><a href=http://dummy.url/example.pdf target="_blank"</a> Example</td>
```

*Example* is not clickable using older browsers but is with newer ones. Wouldn't code below be better?

```
<td><a href="http://dummy.url/example.pdf" target="_blank"> Example</a></td>
```

Comment: Text after an anchor tag is perfectly valid. It will result in a link of zero width (thus completely invisible). The opening tag, however, needs to be closed properly: `<a href="#"></a> Example`

Answer (score 1):

No. There is a missing `>` for the start tag. Notice the code highlighting is broken in your first example. Different browsers "correct" incorrect HTML in different ways.

You can attempt to validate it here:

https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Answer (score 0):

The first code is invalid, some browsers can render it but this not mean that it's valid.

Answer (score 0):

Below code in your question is valid HTML code. It should work on all browsers. There is no error in above second line of code

Answer (score -2):

I dont know much but i think the href should be in quotes since it should be string, as for the text after anchor i never tried it before.. I dont know if it has something to do with the target element referring to other element with name blank though cant test it on phone